# Join two MYSQL Database tables and check if second table has no record then return FALSE and if a column has some specific value then also FALSE

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables one for participants and one for shortlisted candidate. **participants** table have list of all applicants for a test, and **shortlisted** table has only shortlisted candidate. In the second table data gets inserted once a user click on shortlist button in UI (This part is correct). And when the user click the same button twice that candidate gets removed from shortlist (I have a fields "status" in **shortlisted** table and a flag value **removed** is set in it to un-shortlist the candidate)

Now when i try to pull all candidates using the following query i am not getting the desired output.

My requirement is to pull all candidates who are not shortlisted.

P.S If a student has not been selected once, there won't be any entry for that student in **shortlisted** table. If a student has been selected once and the removed, there will be an entry with his detail in **shortlisted** table with status **removed**

My current query is as follows

```
    SELECT DISTINCT(gca.leaderEmail)lemail,
gca.leaderId,
gca.leaderName, 
gca.leaderMobile, 
gca.clgName, 
gca.t1Name, 
gca.t2Name, 
gca.id caseApplyId, 
gca.caseId caseId, 
gu.profile_pic,
        CASE WHEN gcs.id IS NULL then FALSE else TRUE end as shortlist
        FROM gmmu_case_apply gca
        LEFT JOIN gmmu_users gu ON gu.id = gca.leaderId AND gca.leaderId <> 0
        LEFT JOIN gmmu_case_shortlist gcs ON gcs.applicantId = gca.id
        WHERE gca.caseId = $caseId
```

Can you help me to figure out what wrong i am doing here to achieve my desired output

**Update:**
My requirement is I should get **FALSE** if in second table that candidate has a status = '**removed**' and also **FALSE** in case there is no matching JOIN for that user in Second table. I want the return of the alias **shortlist** either to be TRUE or FALSE I have reached some distance with this line in the query above

```
CASE WHEN gcs.id IS NULL then FALSE else TRUE end as shortlist
```

Comment: Might be worth checking out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819471/find-unmatched-records

Comment: Thanks @Fluffeh for the link but it's solving one part.. not the whole i think so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to change your join on gmmu_case_shortlist to an LEFT JOIN as well. The query as you have it written is only going to return records that are in both gca and gcs.

Also, your case statement needs to be modified to check gcs.status for 'removed'  like:

```
CASE WHEN gcs.status='removed' THEN FALSE 
     WHEN gcs.id is null THEN FALSE 
     else TRUE 
end as shortlist
```

Comment: Ohh yes @MartinPicker ... my bad i will update it to left join as that should be their

Comment: No @MartinPicker ... but yes it solved another issue that was not actually pulling records from first table.. Good thanks for pointing that out.. but no actually not solved my problem

Comment: Based on your update shouldn't your case statement look like: "CASE WHEN gcs.status='removed' THEN FALSE WHEN  gcs.id is null THEN FALSE else TRUE end as shortlist"

Comment: Yes got it @MartinPicker i used OR now my query is CASE WHEN gcs.id IS NULL OR gcs.currentStatus = 'removed' then FALSE else TRUE end as shortlist

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys finally solved it and thanks to @MartinPicker for his help so my new query is

```
    SELECT DISTINCT(gca.leaderEmail)lemail,
gca.leaderId,
gca.leaderName, 
gca.leaderMobile, 
gca.clgName, 
gca.t1Name, 
gca.t2Name, 
gca.id caseApplyId, 
gca.caseId caseId, 
gu.profile_pic,
        CASE WHEN gcs.id IS NULL OR gcs.currentStatus = 'removed' then FALSE else TRUE end as shortlist
        FROM gmmu_case_apply gca
        LEFT JOIN gmmu_users gu ON gu.id = gca.leaderId AND gca.leaderId <> 0
        LEFT JOIN gmmu_case_shortlist gcs ON gcs.applicantId = gca.id
        WHERE gca.caseId = $caseId
```